# VSCodeVim Normal Mode Key Bindings ^ Setting

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am using vscode with vim (by extension vscodevim),
But some my setting in the vim is not work

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before":["h","h"],
        "after":["^"]       
    }
]
```

But the insert mode is fine

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before":["h","h"],
        "after":["<Esc>","^"]
    }
]
```

I want to Go to beginning of line by `h`+`h`

It work when insert mode but not in normal mode ?
How to fix it ?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? I am using VSCode (v1.52) and vscodevim(v1.18.9) on Windows 10 and your `"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [` section works for me. I am still experiencing some issues with normal mappings (`["g", "y"] => ["\"", "+", "y"]`) but your case worked for me.

Comment: Actually, my issue was solved by switching to visual mode in vscode settings: `"vim.visualModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [{ "before": ["g", "y"], "after": ["\"", "+", "y"] }]`. There are more options on the [VSCodeVim readme](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/#key-remapping).